# Monitor calibrated and new profile generated but now Adobe InDesign colours look bad

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, monitor

I just calibrated both my monitors using DisplayCal & Spyder5 - I am very happy with colours of the monitors. However, when I load Adobe InDesign CC my reds look awful. (Left is my choosing red - Right is the same red when in the document)

[image]

How can fix this? I have been searching all over - I tried changing profiles and even that didn't work.

Without a fix, all my previous InDesign Documents now look dull.

I just tried (R:255 G:0 B:0) in Adobe Photoshop and it looks a normal red, unlike the red in InDesign.

Thanks

Comment: Thats because indesign is previewing what it looks like in CMYK, which indeed is not as bright as red

Comment: But I never had this issue before I calibrated my screen? How do I stop it from previewing what it looks like in CMYK?

Comment: Disable proofing?

Comment: Also what colorspace did you calibrate your screen to? And what is your working profile

Comment: If by Colorspace you mean Tone Curve I set it to Gamma 2.2, Whitepoint: 6500K and White Level: 140.

I tried most of working profiles but currently is set to Nort America General Purpose 2.

If I disable the working profiles (or set it to 'Emulate Adobe InDesign 2.0 CMS Off') it does display colours correctly. But why has this changed - just because I calibrated my screen? Can I leave it off?

Comment: No, when you calibarted you were asked to claibrate to sRGB or something to that matter. If you didnt then yes i can see your problem. Seem sto me you didnt calubrate it but profile

Comment: I used DispalCal to calibrated and created a profile

Comment: Yes profiling is different from calibrating, calibrating ensures your image is made to fit a standard, profiling just tells you how it works. Now there is a bit of difference between these, if you calibrate as your ttile says, then you turn your monitor into a standard space monitor so what you see is what i see on a standard monitor. If you profile then you only record the way your monitor is different, whch means that you can begin to understand whet others look on your monitor, However, what you see when not managed is NOT the same as others see. Problem, if you use to other apps.

Comment: If you calibrated then you need to know WHAT space you calibrated to?

Comment: Have you ever used DisplayCal? Do you know what would be the best settings to use?

Comment: There is no best setting it depends on what you want to be doing. Do you prepare for print, web or video. If you dont know what your doiung then best to calibrate to sRGB

Comment: DisplayCal has a setting for sRGB, I am going to give that a try and see how it goes. If that doesn't work I might end up trying the Spyder Software.

Comment: In the end, I had to uninstall and install Adobe InDesign. After that, the issue with the colours is gone. Thank you for you time joojaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I had to uninstall and install Adobe InDesign. After that, the issue with the colours is gone.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73510)

Comment: @Ovaryraptor In this case it is an answer to the question though